# Is blender capable enough to model this?

Tags: modeling

let's say I have a solid cylinder surrounded by a cloth like pipe. I want to bunch up the cloth to one end without it going inside the cylinder.

[image]

is there a way to make parts of the cloth move and collide with itself as parts underneath it moves up?

Comment: Yes, Blender definitely is capable of this.

Comment: explain⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: I know it is capable of doing what you're asking, but I myself have forgotten almost all the specific techniques and am having to relearn them now myself. So, I'd suggest you watch youtube tutorials for your version of blender--that's what I'm doing. After you watch enough tutorials, you will eventually figure out the necessary techniques. Or, you can search for cloth tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do this dynamically.

Add a rigid body to your underlying object, add a cloth simulation to your outer pipe and enable self collision.

Now it's just a matter of adjusting the cloth simulation settings to get what you want.

Comment: it just billows in place

Comment: @giwedolus You need to apply some force to it... Use gravity? Animate some object that pushes it? Use one of the physics force systems?